# Calculate Fourier series of $f$, but there are multiple $f(x)$'s.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I've been asked to calculate the Fourier series for $f$, however, I've been given two $f(x)$'s (see below). I know how to calculate Fourier coefficients and the Fourier series but in this case, I'm not sure what to do since there are multiple $f(x)$'s. Do I just calculate the first one? Or do I need to do both?
\begin{align*}
& f(x) = \frac{x}{\pi },\text{ if } - \pi  \le x < \pi ,
\\ &
f(x) = f(x + 2\pi ).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not multiple $f(x)$s, there is just one. $f$ is a periodic function with a period of $2\pi$.

In particular:

- on the interval $[-\pi, \pi)$, the value of $f(x)$ is $\frac{x}{\pi}$.
- On the interval $[-3\pi, -\pi)$, the value of $f(x)$ is equal to $f(x)=f(x+2\pi)=\frac{x+2\pi}{\pi}$.
- On the interval $[\pi, 3\pi)$, the value of $f(x)$ is (because you can show that $f(x)=f(x-2\pi))$ $f(x)=\frac{x-2\pi}{\pi}$.

In general, on the interval $[(2k-1)\pi, (2k+1)\pi)$, the value of $f(x)$ is equal to $f(x)=\frac{x-2k\pi}{\pi}$.

Comment: Ok, that clears a lot up, but then what is the function who's fourier series I need to find? Is it the last f(x) you put? Can I still find its fourier series if it has 'x' and 'k' in it?

Comment: It is the linear function equal to $-1$ at $-\pi$, and $1$  at $\pi$, reproduced periodically outside the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ with the global formula $\;f(x)=f(x\bmod 2\pi)$.

Comment: @Maximus I will say it again: **THERE IS ONLY ONE FUNCTION**.